# Multi-select TextInput in react native android

Tags: multi-select, react-native

I want to make multi-select TextInput in react native android.
There is a example in react.
this is link:
                          https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

I want to do same thing in react native but I am not able to do this.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: No. I just made my own simple selector.

Comment: @pankaj Thankur did you open source your simple selector?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be late, but here is a package I created and might be useful. [react-native-multiple-select](https://github.com/toystars/react-native-multiple-select)

Comment: it has issue while using